# По-Ариненому/по-Арининому

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать это наречие?

1. По-Ариненому.
2. По-Арининому.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [**§ 166.**](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=81#pp81) Имена прилагательные, образованные от личных имен, фамилий, кличек при помощи суффиксов *-ов (-ев)* или *-ин* и обозначающие индивидуальную принадлежность, пишутся с прописной буквы, напр.: *Рафаэлева Мадонна, Шекспировы трагедии, Гегелева «Логика», Далев словарь, Иваново детство, Танина книга, Муркины котята*. <...>
> Прописная буква пишется и в наречиях с приставкой *по-*, образованных от прилагательных на *-ин* типа *Танин, Петин, напр.: по-Таниному, по-Наташиному, по-Петиному, по-тёти-Валиному, по-Анны-Петровниному*.

Правильно:
Таня → Танин → по-Таниному;
Наташа → Наташин → по-Наташиному;
Марина → Маринин → по-Марининому;
*Арина → Арин**и**н → по-Арин**и**ному*.

Такие прилагательные иногда называют относительно-притяжательными (суффикса *-ен* в них быть не может).

*— О нет! — **по-Арининому** простонал я. — Ты все-таки это сделала?* (Ю. Лавряшина. Под желтым зонтом).